# cannot assign to the result of this expression - dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm really confused by this.

I've found examples on how to use a Dictionary but none to explain this error.

Here is my code.

```
struct GDuserSettings{
    var GDUserSettings = Dictionary<String, Bool>()
    func getSettings(user: PFUser){
        var settingsquery = PFQuery(className: "ProfileSettings")
        settingsquery.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)
        settingsquery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{(object: PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            self.GDUserSettings["location"] = false
            //self.userDefaults["pushNotifications"] = object?.objectForKey("pushNotifications")
            //self.userDefaults["distanceInMiles"] = object?.objectForKey("distanceInMiles")
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why I can't assign a new key and value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `getSettings` to:

```
mutating func getSettings(user: PFUser) {
    // ...
}
```

In Swift `struct` is a value type, and the methods on it are not allowed to change it unless `mutating` keyword is specified.

> Structures and enumerations are value types. By default, the properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance methods.
>
> However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating behavior for that method. The method can then mutate (that is, change) its properties from within the method, and any changes that it makes are written back to the original structure when the method ends. The method can also assign a completely new instance to its implicit self property, and this new instance will replace the existing one when the method ends.

See: [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html), chapter "Methods", section "Modifying Value Types from Within Instance Methods"